# How long to slow-cook a small corned beef?

Tags: slow-cooking, crockpot, corned-beef

In [honor of the day](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Saint_Patrick%27s_Day) I want to cook corned-beef in our slow-cooker. I've read several recipes that say to cook a 3-4 pound brisket for 9-10 hours. However, the corned-beef I bought is only 2 pounds.

Should I still cook it for 10 hours?

Comment: The longer you leave it in the slow cooker the better it will be. As long as the slow cooker has liquid in it the food won't burn. My mother used to call her slow cooker. The lazy housewifes best friend.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, you should. The long cooking time breaks down the connective tissue in the meat, making it tender. It will take less time to get a two pound brisket up to temperature than a four pound, but we aren't talking hours difference, and longer is definitely better.

Answer (score 0):

The 2kg (4.4lbs) brisket I did a year back spent three days in the slow cooker. Went in first thing Friday morning. Eaten for lunch on Sunday. Your brisket will only be corned beef if you use the appropriate pickling spice. Ensure your brisket is completely thawed before you put it in the slow cooker. Also don't let your butcher cut any of the brisket fat away. It really needs all the fat available to it.

One last thing, with brisket it really pays to buy the highest quality brisket available to you. I did this by accident because I only eat meat that I have personal assurances of quality and even then it was a bit chewy.

Comment: Three days? Links like [this](https://www.delish.com/food-news/a24118472/slow-cooker-safety-tips-timer/) and my searches indicate that most slow cookers will automatically turn off by this time.